# Problem with detecting clicks inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, iframe

I am trying to detect clicks inside a div.
Here is my sample code:

```
<div  id="target">
E' importante ricordare che le attività di trading comportano alti rischi di perdita del capitale investito. Il nostro consiglio è quello di investire la sola cifra che si è disposti a perdere per "scommettere" su quelle valute che riteniamo incrementeranno moltissimo il loro valore sul medio-lungo termine.

<!-- /21735472908/PDF_viewer_leaderboard_PDF -->
<div id="div-gpt-ad-1536529845958-0">
<script>
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1536529845958-0'); });
   setInterval(function(){googletag.pubads().refresh([slot5]);}, 60000);
</script>
</div>
</div>


<script>
$(function() {
  $("document").click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.id == "target" || $(e.target).parents("#target").length) {
      alert("Inside div");
    } 
  });
})
</script>
```

It happens that clicks inside the div are well detected but click on the ad unit, which is inside the div, are not detected! It is like the ad is covers the div.

Is there any solution? If not, I could use different code, for example detecting a click in a certain body area defining pixel coordinates.

Thank you

Comment: you can use hover opration

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`elementFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint) to achieve your approach.

Here's a simple demo.

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  let target = e.target;
  if (target.id == "target" || $(target).parents("#target").length) {
    alert("Inside div");
  }
  else {
    target.hidden = true;
    let ele = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    target.hidden = false;
    if (ele.id == "target" || $(ele).parents("#target").length) {
      alert("Inside div");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#target {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

#ad {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="target">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="ad"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

### **.mouseover():**

Bind an event handler to the "mouseover" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

### **.hover(): source**

Bind one or two handlers to the matched elements, to be executed when the mouse pointer enters and leaves the elements.

Calling $(selector).hover(handlerIn, handlerOut) is shorthand for: $(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);

### **.mouseenter():**

Bind an event handler to be fired when the mouse enters an element, or trigger that handler on an element.

mouseover fires when the pointer moves into the child element as well, while mouseenter fires only when the pointer moves into the bound element.

## What this means

Because of this, .mouseover() is not the same as .hover(), for the same reason .mouseover() is not the same as .mouseenter().

```
$('selector').mouseover(over_function) // may fire multiple times
```

// enter and exit functions only called once per element per entry and exit

```
$('selector').hover(enter_function, exit_function)
```

## HTML

```
<div id="outer">
  Outer
  <div id="inner">
    Inner
  </div>
</div>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

### Example :

```
$( "#outer" ).mouseover(function() {
  $( "#log" ).append( "<div>Handler for .mouseover() called.</div>" );
})
```